# Why I got this number of mappers in Hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop

I have these settings

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize  = 471192911 (449mb)
dfs.blocksize  = 134217728 (128mb)
```

each of my file is around `3500000000 (3.5G)`
Total file length is `2591561019810 (2.4T, 750 files)`

After I started the hadoop job , the total of mappers are 4820.

I know if Hadoop use splitsize as 449mb, the total of mappers make sense. But according how Hadoop compute the splitsize

```
Math.max(minSize, Math.min(maxSize, blockSize));
```

My split size should be `Math(1, Math.min(449mb, 128mb)) = 128mb`.

Why I got splitsize 449mb ?

Comment: Your minsize may be 449mb

Comment: can you check the value of mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. 
The reason I got these number is I used CombineFileInputFormat. The source code shows split size will be accumulated till reaching the max split size.

Answer (score 0):

From grepcode of [FileInputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.7/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java/?v=source) :

```
   /** 
       * Generate the list of files and make them into FileSplits.
       */ 
      public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job
                                        ) throws IOException {
        long minSize = Math.max(getFormatMinSplitSize(), getMinSplitSize(job));
        long maxSize = getMaxSplitSize(job);


 public static long getMinSplitSize(JobContext job) {
    return job.getConfiguration().getLong(SPLIT_MINSIZE, 1L);
  }


public static final String SPLIT_MINSIZE ="mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize";

protected long computeSplitSize(long blockSize, long minSize,
                                  long maxSize) {
    return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(maxSize, blockSize));
  }
```

The only possibility for this to happen is:

`mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` should be `449m`

Answer (score 0):

To Fix it, Change minsize instead of maxsize as below

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize  = 471192911 (449mb)
```